# efficiently save sheets in new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a macro which saves three specific sheets in a new workbook in specific folder. Each time I need to save about 20-30 workbooks. However, I can see that each time when the macro is called a new workbook is generated below in the task line and following some number of the new workbooks (so far it's like 1500+-) a new workbook is created and afterwards it gets closed and so on. The whole thing takes too much time. If I have to generate 20 new workbooks at once it takes like 30sec or more. Is there any way I can make it quicker?

```
    Sheets(Array("Statement", "Current Run", "Stock")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\solved\" & st & ".xlsx", Password:="",    
     WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False
     //Just adding some row before closing
     finalLine.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Run").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Run").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: You're saving every workbook twice. Moving the `SaveAs` to just before the `Close` should help. Then you can modify the last line's `SaveChange parameter to `False`. Beyond that, your question is confusing. I don't understand whether it's 20-30 or 1500 workbooks you're creating. And I don't understand "a new workbook is generated below in the task line."

Comment: well. A new workbook called for example "book 1500" appears in the task manager line and then the name changes to the relevant one for example "Run15" and then it dissapears from the task manager. Then the next workbook appears in the task manager under the name "book 1501" and then it gets renamed and closed and so on.

Comment: That's what I'd expect to see. You are creating and saving workbooks and that's what you are seeing. By "Task Manager," I think you're referring to the pane typically found on the left side of the VBE. Did you try my suggestion? Also, I think toggling `Application.ScreenUpdating` at the beginning and end of your code would help some.

Comment: Hi, yeah I've got Application.ScreenUpdating already. Your suggestion speeded up the whole process a little bit even though not that much but considering that I come from a Java background vba should be a a lot slower. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see some performance improvement if you reduce the number of calls to any particular object. In your case, you're making multiple calls on the `ActiveWorkbook` object, which could be handled in a `With` block, and as others have mentioned using only one call to the `Save` method:

```
Sheets(Array("Statement", "Current Run", "Stock")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    //Just adding some row before closing
    finalLine.Copy
    With .Sheets("Current Run").
        .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\solved\" & st & ".xlsx", Password:="",    
       WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False
    .Close
End With
```

Whether this will be a noticeable improvement, I am not sure. Probably not unless you are doing this many many times inside a loop.  But it is good practice anyways.